# Send Ctrl+Alt+F1, Crtl+Alt+F7 into VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I have a Virtual Box machine with Ubuntu.  I need to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to guest machine, but when I press them it is captured by host.  How can I fix it ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64155/how-to-send-ctrl-alt-fn-to-virtual-box-guest-linux

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can go to fullscreen in the guest OS by pressing <kbd>Host</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. The default <kbd>host</kbd> key is <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.

Once inside the full screen of Guest OS, try sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. It should be captured as desired.

Comment: i used Host+F to enter fullscreen, but Ctrl+Alt+F1 was still captured by the host

Comment: Doing `Host + F1` took me to the `Ctrl + Alt  + F1` screen in the VM!

Comment: Doing `Host`+`F1` **works** indeed, but when the `Host` key **implies another helper key** (often labeled `fn`), one must be careful to **release** that key before pressing `F1`, else the host will catch `fn`+`F1`, which may be anything, from nothing to suspend host system, turn of wifi/display/audio, and fail to send `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` to the guest. Releasing `Fn` after pressing the `Host` key works wonderfully.

Answer (score 91):

<kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> worked for me without going into fullscreen

Comment: right control f1 didn't work for me, fullscreen or not because my machine grabbed it first, but right control f2 did work and got me to a terminal which is all I wanted.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Just in case anyone needs, if one needs to send **Ctrl + Alt** to a guest machine (just those two keys together, without a third one), one can simply press **Ctrl + Alt** (the wanted keys themselves). https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=69058

Comment: Right Ctrl + F1 did not seem work for me, but in fact it was because gues OS loaded at 1st vt by default, so it did nothing. Right Ctrl+Fn worked.

Comment: `Right Ctrl + Left Alt + F1` worked for me.

Comment: This is not necessarily `R-Ctrl + F1`, but instead `Host + F1`, or `Host + ?` whatever, which sends `Ctrl Alt + ?`.

Comment: For me it only worked after I enabled Auto Capture Keyboard in Input -> Keyboard Settings