# Virtualbox Ubuntu switching to virtual terminal problem

Tags: 16.04, unity, virtualbox, shortcut-keys, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu within Ubuntu using VirtualBox. I want to switch to virtual terminal on guest system. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> within guest system, host system switches to virtual terminal instead of guest system. Although, lock screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) working as expected within guest system.

My question is, is there a way to make my guest system to switch virtual terminal.

VirtualBox version is 5.2 and both guest and host machines are running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: you can assign some other keyboard shortcut to it maybe?

Comment: I can't find the relevant shortcut in the keyboard shortcut settings. How do I assign?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html

Comment: The link you gave doesn't contain any information about virtual terminal.

Comment: After Takkat's answer, I have found out that similar question has been asked before and already has an answer. Possible duplicate of [Send Ctrl+Alt+F1, Crtl+Alt+F7 into VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542328/send-ctrlaltf1-crtlaltf7-into-virtualbox)

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes I did by using Host + F4 keys.

Comment: Ok cool. That is the only thing that matters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VirtualBox we can switch to a TTY in virtual Ubuntu with

<kbd>Host</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> ... <kbd>Host</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>

where<kbd>Host</kbd> ist the host key as was defined in the VirtualBox general settings (usually right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>)